# Feasible reason for a world to move all of its sick, orphaned, incarcerated and elderly population to an isolated continent

Tags: society, alternate-worlds, population, dystopia

Is there any plausible reason (abstract or otherwise) why a world and its population would decide to permanently move/exile all orphans, sick population,incarcerated and elderly population to an isolated region?

Update: I have added the incarcerated percentage of the population to the question too.

Comment: No rational reason, unless there is some infectious thing going on. 
If they don't want to kill them off, moving them far away and keeping them alive there is a lot of trouble. The reason can be religious, or ideological, like - "We are building a perfect society here, and only young, healthy and well-reared can be the builders."

Comment: "and keeping them alive" does not appear in the question. "Grandpa went to live in a land across the sea. No, really he did: Here's a picture of him being eaten by wild dogs there."

Comment: Why bother with moving them? To get the "dogs picture"?

Comment: @Fendec do you mean a one time migration, a permanent exile, a temporary trip, or a culture where people are continually going as they fall into one of those categories?

Comment: Sounds like an alternative world with the Youth Wing of the Khmer Rouge running the show. Year Zero on a global scale.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. 

I was thinking of a situation where the worlds majority population wants to separate all it's ailments from itself and put them in an area where they can live their lives to end but not have the more Utopian parts of the world reminded everyday of their existence. 

Essentially put all the bad parts of society in a closet somewhere to tidy up the other parts of the world. Thus creating a  dystopian region.

Yes I was thinking of a culture where if someone fell into one of these categories they would be exiled to the nether region.

Comment: Orphan doesn't seem to fit, if you're getting rid of people who don't seem productive (one could argue about the value or cost-benefit of the others, especially if sick means chronic illness or disability).  Between the fact everyone loses their parents eventually, and that orphans certainly can become fit and productive members of society, it seems unwise.  If you're going for not wanting to be reminded of mortality, then you need a small (dystopian) nation of young fit lotus eaters picked *out* of the general population, because the unhappy/untidy parts of society is, yanno, everyone.

Answer (score 4):

**For the benefit of the sick, orphaned and elderly**

The populous regions of your world are heavily industrialised - to the point where the air quality poses a significant health risk to everyone, particularly the sick and elderly.

*Sick* people are temporarily relocated to health care facilities in clean air regions, and returned home when they have recovered.

*Elderly* people are permanently relocated to clean air regions. Their contribution to society during their working days is commended and they live out their lives in leisure.

*Orphaned* people are considered the "property" of the state, and drafted into healthcare and service roles to support the sick and elderly.

Comment: This is definitely in the right direction but I was thinking more of a permanent relocation of these groups of the population

Answer (score 0):

Societies can and have come up with many reasons and methods to remove various undesirables, but usually they just kill them, or drive them out of the immediate area.  The only reason I can think of to go to all of the effort of keeping them alive and transporting them to a far away place (a separate continent is going to be a long expensive trip) is if they are being sacrificed in some manner to save the rest of the population.

We send the less productive, less wanted members of society (they would also send the criminals) to the far off land as a sacrifice to the [Gods, Dragons, Vampires, Aliens... evil malevolent monsters of your choice] lest they grow angry (and hungry) and come and destroy the kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

**Marketing**

In the nazy germany the idea of the "ARYAN" race was superior to everything else was enough to start a segregation and genocide.

You just need to push the idea that after certain age you become a burden and need to stay aside for the greater good and people unaffected and that "feel" a gain from it would support it.

Comment: @AlexP Sorry, my mistake I was thinking in spanish. edited :)

Answer (score 0):

I would respond: Australia. When discovered, Australia was a brand new continent, and lots of ships were sent there for settlers to settle (and later, for prisoners of the Britain Empire to be sent to hell since they discovered that any species can kill you in Australia). So was when America was discovered.

Agree, usually people send young men with good health for exploration, treasure-hunting and most of the miscommunication with locals that could turn wrong, but what if your continent is special (like, not interesting or inherently dangerous) and due to a recent war, you send there every prisoner of the country who lost? Including families and children?